# XSLT result-document supress or replace not allowed windows filename characters

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I use xslt 3.0 to output several files with result-document but there is illegal character in windows filenames like " so I tried to use character map:

```
<xsl:character-map name="winfilename">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#34;" string="&#39;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#58;" string="&#59;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#60;" string="&#40;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#62;" string="&#41;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#47;" string="&#45;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#92;" string="&#45;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#63;" string="&#33;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#94;" string="&#39;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

but It doesn't work when I use "use-character-maps" with "result-document".
What's wrong ?

EDIT: this is the code beginning

```
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" use-character-maps="wf"/>
<xsl:mode name="start" streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:character-map name="wf">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#34;" string="&#39;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#58;" string="&#59;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#60;" string="&#40;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#62;" string="&#41;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#47;" string="&#45;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#92;" string="&#45;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#63;" string="&#33;"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#94;" string="&#39;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
<xsl:template match="/" mode="start">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="databank_export/copy-of(db_entry)" mode="entry"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="db_entry">
    <xsl:result-document href="file:///E:\result\//{./public_data/sflname}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" use-character-maps="wf">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="public_data"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

this is not working: error XTSE0350 unescaped left curly bracket
Should I escape curly brackets ?

```
<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/result/{replace(./public_data/sflname,'[&quot;&lt;&gt;/\:?^]','[&apos;&#40;&#41;--;!-]')}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8">
```

I want to output each entry of my database to a "sflname".dat file.
I finally get streaming and serialization to work but some sflname strings contains invalids char for windows pathfile so I want to translate them in order not to lose readability. But even if I follow the example you have shawn.

```
<xsl:template match="db_entry">
    <xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/result/{translate(./public_data/sflname,'[&quot;&lt;&gt;&#47;&#92;&#58;&#63;&#94;]','[&apos;&#40;&#41;&#45;&#45;&#59;&#33;&#39;]')}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="public_data"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

I get the following error:

```
    Unexpected token ';!']')'
    Erreur d'emplacement : xsl:stylesheet / xsl:template / xsl:result-document / @href
    Détails
    XPST0003: The expression around 'sflname,'["<>/\:?^]','['()--;!']')' is not a valid instance of the XPath grammar
```

Why? Should I remove square bracket ? Do some characters need to be double escaped ? I am a very beginner and I don't know. It seems correct according to w3 xpath refs and example.

Best regards

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `translate()` function?

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve with your latest `replace` attempt, in general the second string is a replacement string, not a list of replacement characters. So `translate`, as already suggested, might be a better tool if you want to replace each character in a string with corresponding character in another string. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-replace and https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-translate

Comment: I want to output each entry of my database to a "sflname".dat file. I finally get streaming and serialization to work but some sflname strings contains invalids char for windows pathfile so I want to translate them in order not to lose readability.

Comment: See the edit to my answer on one approach on how to use a single quote safely in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character map would be applied when serializing text data in a result tree, not when using a file name. So you would need to use the `replace` function where you construct the file name e.g. `<xsl:result-document href="replace(url, '[list of characters here]', '')">`. `url` in the snippet is meant as an example element name containing your file name with the characters to be removed or replaced.

In your code snippet, you have to create a URI which uses forwards slashes so instead of

```
<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:\result\//{./public_data/sflname}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" use-character-maps="wf">
```

you need

```
<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/result/{public_data/sflname}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" use-character-maps="wf">
```

And if `public_data/sflname` can contain characters you need to remove or replace then use e.g.

```
<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/result/{replace(public_data/sflname, '[list of characters]', '')}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8" use-character-maps="wf">
```

As already explained, the character map is only helpful and useful for any replacement you want to do on text data in the output you want to create, not for the file name or URI.

As for your latest struggle to use `translate`, it is simply a problem to use the right syntax of XML and XPath to quote strings with an apostrophe/single quote inside, there are various pitfalls related to that and various ways to avoid them, I would suggest to define two global parameters

```
<xsl:param name="chars-to-be-replaced" as="xs:string">&quot;&lt;&gt;&#47;&#92;&#58;&#63;&#94;</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="replacement-chars" as="xs:string">&apos;&#40;&#41;&#45;&#45;&#59;&#33;&#39;</xsl:param>
```

and then in your translate call you can simply use

```
<xsl:result-document href="file:///E:/result/{translate(./public_data/sflname, $chars-to-be-replaced, $replacement-chars)}.dat" method="text" encoding="UTF-8">
```

Of course there is not really a need to use character or entity references for most of those characters but I suppose that is based on your earlier approach to use character maps, you could write it clearer as e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="chars-to-be-replaced" as="xs:string"><![CDATA["<>/\:?^]]></xsl:param>
```

respectively

```
<xsl:param name="replacement-chars" as="xs:string">'()--;!'</xsl:param>
```

Comment: So this was about the &apos; entity I was guessing it. But this is not working with saxonEE with database. The program run but no file is written then the program end with no error message. XMLspy work with a small 36 entries db.

Comment: Make sure you run Saxon with the `-t` option to see/check which files it writes to which location. If you still have problems then post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry to have make you lose your time . Sorry. A word in a path was missing somewhere and it wasn't working.